# Statistics testing

Tags: probability, statistics

On a math test at a certain large school, a random sample of $61$ women had a mean score of $64$ and standard deviation of $14$ and a random sample of $61$ men had a mean score of $60$ and standard deviation of $12$. Can we conclude that the women at this school are better in math than men with $5\%$ level of significance?

Which test should be used?

Comment: If you've seen two-sample t-tests mentioned, then you haven't understood them if you don't recognize this as typical.

Comment: Why not migrate this question to Cross Validated, the sister statistics site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comment:** I assume those are *sample* standard deviations. Also that the populations of test scores are normal.

There are two
kinds of two-sample t tests: 'pooled' and 'separate variances (Welch)'.
Unless you have strong reason (aside from the data) to believe *population* variances are equal, then the Welch test is preferred. Output from Minitab
statistical software for the Welch test, based the data summaries provided, is shown below:

```
Two-Sample T-Test

Sample   N  Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       61  64.0   14.0      1.8
2       61  60.0   12.0      1.5

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  4.00
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs >): 
  T-Value = 1.69  P-Value = 0.046  DF = 117
```

The crucial bit of output is nearly the same for the pooled test: `T-Value = 1.69  P-Value = 0.046  DF = 120`.

The null hypothesis is rejected (just barely) at the 5% level.
I will leave it to you to match computations from formulas in your
text with those of Minitab.